# Trying to write my on version of mesg

Tags: linux, c

I am tasked with writing my own version of write and at first thought I could use IXOFF as in the following code to stop all input coming in:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main( int ac, char** args )
{

struct termios ttyinfo;
ttydrv=tcgetattr(0, &ttyinfo);

ttyinfo.c_iflag |=IXOFF;
        tcsetattr(0,TCSANOW, &ttyinfo);
        if(ttyinfo.c_iflag &IXOFF)
        {
            printf("flow control of input is off\n");
        }



}
```

Now I am looking for other ideas. If devices are like files could I change the persmissions on other for the tty to exclude write permissions? Any other ideas?

Comment: Setting IXOFF just means the user will be able to type ^S and ^Q to stop and start output on the tty. In any case, you don't want to disable *all* output to the tty, you just want to set a flag or permission bit somewhere that will make the `write` program be unable to access your tty. Historically, mesg called `ttyname(0)`, called `stat` on that, and used `chmod` to turn on or off a bit in the `st_mode` field (S_IWGRP, I think) that would prevent `write` from opening the tty for writing.

Comment: Thanks after some research and playing I was able to manually change the persmissions like a file. I am going to look at what you said about stat since I am famliar with dealing with the struct. One other question how could I get a list of user logged in?

Comment: I'd probably call [getutxid](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/endutxent.html) repeatedly, looking for USER_PROCESS entries.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I got the open terminal by system("tty >> temp.txt"). I have another issue but I will ask it as another question.